# Increment variable in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, I want to query a table like so:

```
 | ID | Number 
 -------------
 |  1 |   0    
 |  2 |   0    
 |  3 |   1    
 |  4 |   0    
 |  5 |   0    
 |  6 |   1    
 |  7 |   1    
 |  8 |   1
```

The result should be the same table with an additional column that counts.

The method of counting is: if the number in "number" equals to 1 - increment the counter by one for the **next** line.

An example of result for the provided table:

```
 | ID | Number | Counter
 -----------------------
 |  1 |   0    |    1
 |  2 |   0    |    1
 |  3 |   1    |    1
 |  4 |   0    |    2
 |  5 |   0    |    2
 |  6 |   1    |    2
 |  7 |   1    |    3
 |  8 |   1    |    4
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you use?

Comment: Any way to achieve this without sub-queries?

Comment: I think that if you work on `MySQL` it is possible to do it with out subquery but in `Sql Server` i don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select [ID], [Number],
       isnull(1+(select sum([Number]) from Table1 t2 where t2.ID<t1.Id),1)
from Table1 t1
```

**[SQL Fiddle to test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21a96/1)**

Answer (score 1):

This is not too hard to do. What you are looking for is very much like the running total, which you get with sum and a windowing clause.

```
select id, num, 1 + sum(num) over (order by id) - num as counter
from mytable
order by id;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/958e2a/1.

Comment: OP is using **`SQL Server`**

Comment: Is it faster then Luv's answer?

Comment: @Luv: The request was only tagged "sql" at first. Anyhow, SQL Server does support window functions. So it only depends on the version wether above query works or not.

Comment: @Itzik Gili: It should be faster. Ideally the table is read just once, which is likely to happen with SUM OVER. In Luv's statement the table must be read again and again.

Comment: Just checked it. SUM OVER is supported in SQL Server 2012, but not in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive select too but it is a bit complicated but if you insert other numbers which are greater than 1 it work fine:

```
with tab(id,number,counter,rn) as
(select t.*,1 as counter,1 as rn from table1 t where id = 1
union all
select t.*,case when t.number = 1 then counter + 1 else counter end as counter,
rn + 1 as rn from table1 t,tab where t.id = tab.rn + 1),
tab2 as (select id,number,counter from tab)
select id,number,case when number = 1 then counter - 1 
else counter end as counter from tab2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1342f/1)